# Convex approximation of non-convex polynomial

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Given $$\min  k_1x + k_2x^{3/2} + k_3x y^{0.5} + k_4y^{3/2} \\ \text {s.t.}  x + y=b \\ \text x>0, y>0, k_i > 0 for 1<=i<=4, b>0$$

Clearly $k_1x$, $k_2x^{3/2}$ and $k_4y^{3/2}$ are convex functions. However, I am not sure if $k_3x y^{0.5}$ is convex. This makes this optimization problem non-convex.
Could someone help me (a) ascertain if $k_3x y^{0.5}$ is concave, (b) if so, then are there any tricks/approximations that I can employ here to get closest convex optimization formulation.

Comment: Get rid of 1/2 exponent.  Let $u=x^{1/2}$ and $v=y^{1/2}$ with $u^2+v^2=b$.

Comment: Thanks @herbsteinberg. Although $\min  k_1u^2 + k_2u^3+ k_3u^2 v + k_4v^3$ (say $g(u,v)$) is convex, wouldn't it be a completely different surface to optimize than $\min  k_1x + k_2x^{3/2} + k_3x y^{0.5} + k_4y^{3/2}$  (say $f(x,y)$)? would $(x,y)=(u^2,v^2)$ where $(x,y) = argmin_{x,y}f(x,y)$ and $(u,v) = argmin_{u,v}g(u,v)$ ?

Comment: My guess: min and convexity questions would have the same answer.

Comment: how to scientifically arrive at this conclusion? Thinking further, is $min_{u,v}k_3u^2v$ really convex?

Comment: Guess is just that.  There was no deep analysis, just a coordinate change might help.